# How to use StrictHostnameVerifier over HttpsURLConnection by API level 22 without deprecation?

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection

This was the code I have used so far:

```
URL request = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) request.openConnection();
urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new StrictHostnameVerifier());
```

However, by **API Level 22** [StrictHostnameVerifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/X509HostnameVerifier.html) is deprecated.

> **This interface was deprecated in API level 22**. 
>   Please use [openConnection()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) instead. Please visit [this webpage](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for further details.

The thing is I was already using `openConnection` with `StrictHostnameVerifier` . I still can use it but I see a deprecated warning on the line

```
urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new StrictHostnameVerifier());
```

Where is the mistake or what is missing?

PS: *Reinventing the wheel and implementing `StrictHostnameVerifier` is out of the question apparently.*

---

**Edit**: Is there anything new regarding new API?

Comment: My guess is that in order to make people stop using the Apache HttpClient, they deprecated every class within that package, including the `HostnameVerifier`s - even though they implement the interface both used by HttpUrlConnection *and* HttpClient... Personally, I'd just suppress the deprecation warning.